# Character buffer being overrun while reading file

Tags: c++, file, struct

I'm trying to read data from a file but I'm getting a STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN error and the app crashes.

I have a struct:

```
struct BSPEntities
{
    char* ents; 
};
```

And I'm reading the file:

```
BSPEntities entities
ifstream mapfile;
int size = 54506;
int offset = 5182600; 

entities.ents = new char[size];
mapfile.seekg(offset, ios::beg);
mapfile.read((char *)(&entities.ents), size);
```

"size" and "offset" are values loaded from the file and known to be valid. I have preprocessor directives #pragma pack(1) and #pragma push around the BSPEntities struct.

Thanks.

Comment: why using raw new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&entities.ents` is a pointer to a pointer to char.  The object pointed to (a pointer to char) is probably only 4 or 8 bytes depending on the architecture you're targeting, but you're trying to write 54,506 bytes to it.  Obviously 54,506 is larger than 8, so you're writing past the end of the pointer, and the behavior is undefined.

That read should just be `mapfile.read(entities.ents, size);`

Also you don't need to mess around with `#pragma pack` here, unless there's something more complicated going on that you're not showing.

Comment: Alright thanks that was the problem. I feel silly now.  I'm using pack and push because VS pads the struct and gives me wrong results when I read the file.

Comment: @Hermetix you are not reading data directly into the struct itself, so the struct padding is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
mapfile.read((char *)(&entities.ents), size);
```

Should be

```
mapfile.read(entities.ents, size);
```

Instead of passing the address of the heap memory block that `ents` points to, you are passing the address of `ents` itself. And since `ents` is being allocated on the stack, you are reading bytes onto the stack until it overruns.

Comment: Just a note that you don't need that `(char *)` cast there.